# Нужна ли запятая в предложении? Какой вариант верный и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Какой вариант верный? Спасибо!

1. Слишком быстро они отнимают у маленького, едва покрытого перьями тельца, драгоценное тепло.
2. Слишком быстро они отнимают у маленького, едва покрытого перьями тельца драгоценное тепло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**О качестве ответа**

Как я себе представляю хороший ответ?

С одной стороны, мы отвечаем **конкретному**, а не абстрактному  автору, поэтому желательно понять ход его мыслей.

С другой стороны, информационная часть ответа должна иметь **безотносительную ценность**, так как  по большому счету каждый ответ влияет на  качественный уровень и престижность  ресурса.

**1.  Почему автор задает подобный вопрос?**  Об этом важно подумать при ответе, иначе он будет формальным.

Это проблема  **«лишних запятых»**, которые ставятся на месте произносительных пауз.  А причина такой паузы в данном случае – **неудачно построенное предложение**.  Оно сложно читается и не сразу понимается, в том числе на слух.

Возможное редактирование: *Слишком быстро они отнимают  **драгоценное тепло** у маленького, // едва покрытого перьями тельца.*

В этом варианте две фразы, запятая  ставится на месте паузы. И порядок слов  обоснованный: сначала прямое дополнение (отнимают что?), а потом косвенное (отнимают у кого?)

Сравним: *Слишком быстро они отнимают у маленького, // **едва покрытого перьями тельца драгоценное тепло**.*

Здесь тоже две фразы, но  вторая фраза (после запятой)  имеет **некорректную  по сочетаемости структуру.**

Поэтому при ответе желательно обратить внимание на данный факт.

**2.  О самом анализе**

Грамматика и структура предложения становятся ясными, если мы просто **уберем распространенное определение,** тогда получится:

*Слишком быстро они отнимают  у (**маленького,  едва покрытого перьями**) тельца драгоценное тепло.*

Предлог **У относится к существительному**, поэтому мы не можем разделить их запятой.  Вот и всё доказательство. Он намного проще приведенного.

Кстати, однородность определений здесь **неочевидна**,  значения разных признаков сближаются в данном тексте  (маленький предмет с незащищенной поверхностью остывает быстрее).

Answer (score 1):

***Слишком быстро они отнимают у маленького, едва покрытого перьями тельца драгоценное тепло***.

Конечно, второй вариант корректный — запятая после слова *тельце* не нужна.

Наверное, если у вас возник такой вопрос, то вы не очень разобрались со структурой предложения, я поясню:

*Они отнимают* (Что?) *тепло* (У кого?) *у тельца* (Какого?) *маленького и едва покрытого перьями.*

*маленького и едва покрытого перьями* — это однородные определения. При отсутствии союза между ними (как в вашем случае) мы ставим запятую.

Больше никаких знаков препинания **НЕ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ**!

У вас же в первом варианте предложения вышел своего рода обособленный оборот, которого, конечно же, там быть не может.

**Запомните:** обособленные обороты, как правило, можно вынуть из предложения, не нарушив при этом его структуру и смысл!

Попробуйте из первого предложения изъять оборот, который у вас вышел:

**Слишком быстро они отнимают у маленького** *, едва покрытого перьями тельца,* **драгоценное тепло**.

У маленького чего?? Как видите, структура нарушена и смысл пропал, а следовательно, вторая запятая там лишняя.